# Relationships between $\operatorname{Alt}(T \otimes S)$ and $\operatorname{Alt(T)} \otimes \operatorname{Alt}(S)$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, permutations, manifolds, tensor-products

> I am reading Calculus on Manifolds, and just out of curiosity, for $T \in J^{k}(V)$, $S \in J^{l}(V)$ does there exist any relationships between $\operatorname{Alt}(T \otimes S)$ and $\operatorname{Alt(T)} \otimes \operatorname{Alt}(S)$?

I am not really familiar with abstract algebra or permutation groups, so I'm not sure how permutation groups with degree k+l are related to two permutation groups each with degree k and l. Nonetheless, I am still curious if there are any relationships between these two things as it might be useful sometime.

Comment: Try it out with $k=\ell=1$. The main point is that the tensor product of the alternating tensors is far from alternating. You still have to fully skew-symmetrize.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. What is fully skew-symmetrize by the way?

Comment: What you have is partially skew-symmetric (the $k$ piece is and the $\ell$ piece is), but if you switch a vector from the first $k$ and a vector from the last $\ell$ there is no negative that appears. An alternating tensor is *fully* skew-symmetric.